# Android Click button to next activity but it freezes the layout

Tags: android, layout, button

I have 3 buttons on each layout. When i clicked on button MOH in results.xml, MOHactivity is invoked and displayed the results_health layout. But when i wanted to click any button in results_health, it is like the screen has frozen. But, if i clicked on BACK button, it will go back to my main activity. I have no idea how to play around with this. Thanks.

ResultsActivity.java is same for Result_PDRM.java & Result_MOH.java(oncreate())

```
       ImageView myMOHButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.MOH_Button);  
        myMOHButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v)
            {  
                setContentView(R.layout.results_health);

            }  
        }); 

        ImageView myPDRMButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.PDRM_Button);  
        myPDRMButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v)
            {  
                setContentView(R.layout.results_pdrm);
            }  
        }); 

        ImageView myMainButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Main_Button);  
        myMainButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v)
            {  
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

            }
        }
        );
```

result.xml is also same with results_health.xml & result_pdrm.xml (results_health don't have MOH ImageView, results_pdrm don't have PDRM ImageView)

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <AbsoluteLayout
         android:id="@+id/widget56"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:background="@drawable/bgnd">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/MOH" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#ff00ff00" android:text="Health Details" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="25sp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_x="6dip" android:layout_y="9dip"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@id/JPJ_Button" android:src="@drawable/jpj1" android:layout_y="425dip" android:layout_x="2dip"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@id/PDRM_Button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/pdrm1" android:layout_x="94dip" android:layout_y="425dip"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@id/JPN_Button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/camera_48" android:layout_x="186dip" android:layout_y="425dip"></ImageView>
      <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@id/Main_Button" android:src="@drawable/camera_small" android:layout_x="277dip" android:layout_y="425dip"></ImageView>
       </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you doing any processor/io-intensive tasks?

Comment: Please be more clear. What is the issue?

Comment: i'm doing some text recognition based on camera capture, then compare the result from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing here is replacing the XML layout for the current activity. The reason it appears frozen is because you slapped a new UI over your code, but didn't attach any ClickHandlers to the buttons because under the hood you were still running the code from the previous activiy.

What you WANT to do is go from one activity to another. To go to another activity, you need to declare an intent.

```
ImageView myMainButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Main_Button);  
        myMainButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v)
            {  
                    Intent i = new Intent(ResultsActivity.this, Result_PDRM.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i,0);
            }
        }
        );
```

This will take you from ResultsActivity to Result_PDRM. Then, in onCreate in Result_PDRM, you call:

```
setContentView(R.layout.results_pdrm);
```

Make sure you have your clickHandlers in Result_PDRM wired up to the proper controls in the XML layout.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better using `startActivity(new Intent(...))` so that you will change your layout *(actually change activity)* because your button *(in old layout)* is still working in new layout